# How to determine $\lim \limits_ {n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{31^ { \frac{n}{5} }}{17^{ \frac{n}{2} } }?$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to compute

$\lim \limits_ {n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{31^ { \frac{n}{5} }}{17^{ \frac{n}{2} } }?$

Wolframalpha gave me the solution $0$ but I dont get how to determine that.

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: As $0\to \infty$? Hint: Rewrite the expression as $c^n$ for some $c$.

Comment: @fragant I'm not going to bother un-reverting since I don't want to bump, but your partial reversion of my edit is against the guidelines [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles). It's also the overwhelming convention in mathematics that mathematical expressions on its own line should be centered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\lim \limits_ {n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{31^ { \frac{n}{5} }}{17^{ \frac{n}{2} } } = \lim \limits_ {n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{31^ { \frac{1}{5} }}{17^{ \frac{1}{2} } }\right)^n = \lim \limits_ {n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{{\left(31^2\right)}^ { \frac{1}{10} }}{{\left(17^5\right)}^{ \frac{1}{10} } }\right)^n  = \lim \limits_ {n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{{31^2}}{17^5}\right)^{n\over10} = 0 $$

since $\left|\frac{{31^2}}{17^5} \right|< 1$

Answer (score 2):

Calculator free estimate:

$$\frac{31^{1/5} }{17^{1/2}}< \frac{32^{1/5} }{16^{1/2}} = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: we have $$961=31^2<17^5=1419857$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{31^ { \frac{n}{5} }}{17^{ \frac{n}{2} } } = \frac{31^ { \frac{n}{5} }}{31^{ \frac{\log_{31}(17)n}{2} } }= 31^{n(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{\log_{31}(17)}{2})} = 31^{c*n} = b^n$

$\lim \limits_ {n \rightarrow \infty}b^n = \{ 0 \text{ if } 0<b<1; \infty \text{ if } b > 1; 1 \text{ if } b = 1\}$

$c = \frac{1}{5}-\frac{\log_{31}(17)}{2} < 0$ as $31^{2/5} < 17$.  So $0< b= 31^c < 1$.

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

$$31^2=961<(17^2)^2<17^5$$

$$\implies31^{1/5}<17^{1/2}$$

Now use $\lim_{n\to\infty}c^n\to0$ for $|c|<1$

Comment: I think you mean $|c|<1$.

Comment: @kccu, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}2^n=?$$

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n=\infty$, but the limit in question is $0$. The $c$ in question is $\frac{31^{1/5}}{17^{1/2}}<1$.

Comment: @kccu, Exactly. $$\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}c^n=0$$ for $|c|<1$

Comment: I believe you initially had $|c|>1$ in your answer.

Comment: @kccu, I wrote $$\lim_{n\to\infty}c^n\to\infty$$  for $|c|>1$ which is true

Comment: Yes, that's true, but that's not what should be used for this problem.